# Set min/max values on mouse position value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the mouse position (x/y) on mousemove... but I'm wondering if it's possible for the x/y position to stop changing value at a certain min and max?

```
$this.mousemove(function(event) {
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;
});
```

Ideally I'd like to have variables `xmin` and `xmax` and `ymin` and `ymax` and only allow the returned value to be within two min and max values (say, between 300 and 900) so as the mouse is moving it would record it's position but anywhere outside 300px and 900px it wouldn't change value.

Possible?

Comment: Why not just check the position before assigning?

Comment: No, you cannot limit mouse movement. But it's trivial to limit the `x` and `y` variables in the respective ranges using `Math.max` and `Math.min`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot easily make it look like the mouse is remaining within a certain range, you can do what you are asking, which is to return either the real y position, or the maximum that you can.

Try this code

```
$this.mousemove(function(event) {
    x = Math.max(
        Math.min(
            event.pageX, xmax
    ), xmin);
    y = Math.max(
        Math.min(
            event.pageX, ymax
    ), ymin);
});
```

The idea is that `Math.max` chooses either the smallest value, or the actual position, whichever is bigger. The `Math.min` does the opposite.